# Sending data continuously through sockets

Tags: android

I'm developing an client application which is sending the current time seconds with another application which is acting as a server. The problem is that when I run my app it is only sending the first messages (e.g. if it is 15:55:02 it starts sending 02 again and again). How can I make my app sending the time seconds continuously?

Here's my code:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity 
{
    private EditText serverIp;

    private EditText sendMsg;

    private Button connectPhones;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

    private boolean connected = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
               if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                connected = true;
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
                int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);
                            out.println(seconds);
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent."+seconds);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error!", e);
                    }
                }
                //Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must re-get the value of second every time you want to send it.

```
while (connected) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
            try {
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                            .getOutputStream())), true);
                    out.println(seconds);
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent."+seconds);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error!", e);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because `seconds` is never changing.  It's outside of the loop.

Try this:

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity 
{
    private EditText serverIp;

    private EditText sendMsg;

    private Button connectPhones;

    private String serverIpAddress = "";

    public static final int SERVERPORT = 8080;

    private boolean connected = false;

    private Handler handler = new Handler();

    private Socket socket;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        serverIp = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        connectPhones = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
        connectPhones.setOnClickListener(connectListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener connectListener = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!connected) {
                serverIpAddress = serverIp.getText().toString();
               if (!serverIpAddress.equals("")) {
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public class ClientThread implements Runnable {

        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Connecting...");
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);
                connected = true;
                Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                while (connected) {
                    try {
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sending command.");
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket
                                    .getOutputStream())), true);
                            out.println(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
                            Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Sent."+seconds);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("ClientActivity", "S: Error!", e);
                    }
                }
                //Log.d("ClientActivity", "C: Closed.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error", e);
                connected = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to flush the stream before sending another message through socket, this should help:

```
out.println(seconds);
out.flush();
```

Comment: I still can't understand why is flush() used?

Comment: The name of the method speaks itself, to flush the stream, any data will be flushed out to the destination.